# Get Values from array of resolved Promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, axios

I am using axios.all to call loop through an array of items and make a get request for each so that I can save their data in the correct order. Right now I have an array of Promises, all of which are being resolved with the correct data, and the callback function for when all of these are done is being triggered.

Now I just need to loop through the Promises and save them their values, but I don't know how to access their values!

```
let promises = [];

for (let report of response.data.res.body.result) {
    let dto2 = {
        customerId: state.member.customerId,
        reportToken: report.reportToken
    }

    promises.push(axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/pullReport', dto2));
}
console.log("promises", promises);

axios.all(promises).then(function() {
    console.log("done!");
    promises.forEach(function(res) {
        console.log("res", res);
        // commit('SAVE_REPORT', res.value);
    })
    // resolve('Reports saved.');
});
```

Here's what each promise looks like when it is consoled in the forEach loop :

```
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Object <<<<<<<<<<< NEED THIS
```

I just need to be able to call the commit('SAVE_REPORT') with the PromiseValue Object, but I don't know what to pass in! I've tried res.value, res.val, res.promiseValue... Is there a secret to this?

Comment: most Promise libraries send each response (in order they were called -- not in order they returned) to the resolve callback. You can destructure by saying `.then(function([res1, res2, res3, etc.])` or you can capture them all into a single array by just saying, `.then(function(responses)`

Comment: What do you get when you console.log(util.inspect(res))?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

axios.all creates a new promise, which will resolve with an array of the results. So to interact with those results, you just need to add a parameter to the function in the .then block:

```
axios.all(promises).then(function(results) {
    results.forEach(function(res) {
        commit('SAVE_REPORT', res.value);
    });
});
```

Comment: Consider using `Promise.all` instead, as `axios.all` seems to be going for deprecation.

Comment: Also switching to Promise.all. Thanks :)